# ArgumentError: Plotly not found in path in Julia

Tags: macos, pip, julia, plotly, ijulia-notebook

I have installed `plotly using`pip`in`OS X`:

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:~ mona$ pip install plotly
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): plotly in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from plotly)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from plotly)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from plotly)
```

When I am trying to use it in `julia` I get the following error:

```
julia> using Plotly
ERROR: ArgumentError: Plotly not found in path
 in require at /Applications/Julia-0.4.3.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install Plotly, the Julia package:

```
Pkg.add("Plotly")
```

Check [here](https://plot.ly/julia/getting-started/) to set it up.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It was very useful. Do you know why the plots are not shown in Jupyter? http://imgur.com/u4uZI7d

Comment: I'm not sure, don't use plotly often; did you try fixing the warnings?

Comment: no I still have them with your method or with the link's method: `WARNING: deprecated syntax "[a=>b, ...]" at In[8]:5.
Use "Dict(a=>b, ...)" instead.

WARNING: deprecated syntax "[a=>b, ...]" at In[8]:10.
Use "Dict(a=>b, ...)" instead.`

Comment: The website with the instructions has not been updated to the new Dict syntax, but the message is telling you what you need to do: instead of using `[a => b, ...]` to create a Dict, use `Dict(a => b, ...)`, see http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/collections/#associative-collections

Comment: You can use much of plotly through the `Plots` package interface without installing the `Plotly` package. Load `Plots`, then (if you have more than one) set the backend with `plotly()`.